# Android Development: Opening link in browser without using Activity

Tags: java, android, browser, game-physics

I'm developing a game on Android. On the Main Menu Screen, I wish to provide a link to my website.. 
This screen is an image, which has touch events for carrying out different actions.
The link to my website should also be a result of a touchEvent.

My MainMenuScreen.java extends another java file, and cannot extend Activity.

**Can you please suggest how I can redirect the user to the website, using a touch event, but without making it an activity.**

Here's a section of the code within my MainMenuScreen.java (here the extended Screen is an abstract class defined by me, which is used to extend all screens in the game)

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends Screen {
public MainMenuScreen(Game game) {
    super(game);
}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

            if (inBounds(event, 50, 300, 250, 450)) {
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            }
            if(inBounds(event, 370, 300, 600, 450)) {
                // Needs the code to redirect user to website
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference to the android.view.View that draws your Screen (or your class Screen extends View), you can do this:

```
Context context = view.getContext(); // or Context context = getContext();
if (context instanceof Activity) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) context;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: By the way, you can use any context to start an activity. Sometimes people make a static variable in their application object and use it as the context everywhere.